# Does the specific signed integer matter when implementing compareTo in a Comparable <Type> class?

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

When implementing `compareTo()`, does the degree of "difference" need to be taken into account?

For instance, if I have 3 objects, C1, C2, and C3, such that C1 < C2 < C3.

Should C1.compareTo(C2) return an integer that is less than C2.compareTo(C3)?

The documentation for the Comparable interface doesn't seem to specify one way or another, so I'm guessing the degree doesn't matter, but it would be nice to know if there is some advantage returning a specific number (for example, improving TreeSet sort speed or something).

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question, but nonetheless no, the magnitude of the `int` has no significance as per `Comparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>` specifications, only the sign. Conceivably some sorting algorithm can additionally specify that they can take "hints" from the magnitude, but I'm not sure how practical that would be for comparison-based sorting, since we really need only to know if `a < b`, `a == b`, or `a > b` (which is really what `Comparable` and `Comparator` are OOP abstractions of).

---

Now it needs to be said that there may be a hidden intention here of using the subtraction idiom for comparing numeric values, i.e. something like this:

```
public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
    return t1.intField - t2.intField;
}
```

Do note that this comparison method is *potentially* broken, due to possible overflow when the difference between the two numbers is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In fact, this is one of the puzzles covered in [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

To demonstrate, consider the following snippet (taken from the book):

```
int x = -2000000000;
int z = 2000000000;
System.out.println(x - z); // prints a positive number due to overflow
```

Clearly `x < z`, and yet `x - z` is a positive number. Beware of using this subtraction idiom: it's always much safer to do an explicit comparison and `return -1`, `0`, or `1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

no, the only difference is between negative numbers, 0, and positive numbers. the degree is irrelevant.